# Легко расширяемый калькулятор на Java

Tags: java

Добрый день. 
Подскажите плиз варианты.
Изначально есть калькулятор который умеет складывать, делить, умножать, вычитать числовые типы: int, long, float, double.
Хочу добавить операцию остаток от деления и ввести новый тип данных, например Дата.
Подскажите структуру программы, чтобы можно было легко расширять библиотеку?
Спасибо.

Comment: Под калькулятором имеется ввиду полный синтаксический разбор строки и вычисление результата?

Answer (score 1):

Вводить интерфейс ICalc, реализовывать функцию calc(params), создавать дочерние классы "наследники" интерфейса, реализовывать логику каждого действия. А что структура - ---calc. -> MainApp.class ---handlers -> ICalc, Plus, ...., .class